# VirtualBox Guest Additions compilation

Tags: c++, virtualbox, kbuild

I'm compiling VirtualBox Guest Additions according to official [documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Windows%20build%20instructions#LocalConfig). Building separately 64- and 32-bit additions and trying to pack it into iso image.

Target system is Windows 7 x64. All software requirements as per documentation, including exact versions. Only additions should be built (VBOX_ONLY_ADDITIONS := 1 in LocalConfig.kmk)

32-bit compilation without setting a target

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /Release /x86 /win7
set BUILD_TARGET_ARCH=x86
set PATH=%PATH%;%~dp0kBuild\bin\win.x86
cscript configure.vbs --with-DDK=C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1 --with-MinGW-w64=C:\mingw\mingw64 --with-MinGW32=C:\mingw\mingw32 --with-libSDL=C:\SDL\x86\SDL-1.2.15 --with-openssl=C:\OpenSSL\x32 --with-libcurl=C:\curl\x86 --with-Qt5=C:\Qt\5.6.3\x86\msvc2010 --with-python=C:/Python27
call env.bat
kmk KBUILD_TARGET_ARCH=x86
```

64-bit compilation without setting a target

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /Release /x64 /win7
set BUILD_TARGET_ARCH=amd64
set PATH=%PATH%;%~dp0kBuild\bin\win.amd64
cscript configure.vbs --with-DDK=C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1 --with-MinGW-w64=C:\mingw\mingw64 --with-MinGW32=C:\mingw\mingw32 --with-libSDL=C:\SDL\x64\SDL-1.2.15 --with-openssl=C:\OpenSSL\x64 --with-openssl32=C:\OpenSSL\x32 --with-libcurl=C:\curl\x64 --with-libcurl32=C:\curl\x86 --with-Qt5=C:\Qt\5.6.3\x64\msvc2010 --with-python=C:/Python27
call env.bat
kmk KBUILD_TARGET_ARCH=amd64
```

Trying to build x86 additions (according to comments in Makefile.kmk, must be built before x64)

```
kmk additions-build-win.x86
```

Getting the error

```
kBuild: Creating C:/Users/atatat/Projects/virtualbox/VirtualBox-5.2.2/out/win.x86/release/bin/additions/VBoxWHQLFake.exe
C:/Users/atatat/AppData/Local/Temp/make3416-1.sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
kmk.exe[1]: *** [C:/Users/atatat/Projects/virtualbox/VirtualBox-5.2.2/out/win.x86/release/bin/additions/VBoxWHQLFake.exe] Error 2 (0x2)
kmk.exe[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/atatat/Projects/virtualbox/VirtualBox-5.2.2'
kmk_time: 0m2.823600s - exit code: 2
kmk: *** [additions-build-win.x86] Error 2 (0x2)
```

Same error appears trying to build x64 version: `kmk additions-build-win.amd64`

My LocalConfig.kmk

```
VBOX_WITH_HARDENING :=
VBOX_PATH_WIX := C:\wix
VBOX_GSOAP_INSTALLED := 1
VBOX_PATH_GSOAP := C:\gsoap\gsoap-2.8\gsoap
VBOX_WITH_COMBINED_PACKAGE := 1
VBOX_WITH_QT_PAYLOAD := 1
VBOX_WITH_QTGUI_V5 := 1
VBOX_SIGNING_MODE := release
VBOX_TSA_URL := http://timestamp.digicert.com
VBOX_TSA_SHA2_URL := http://timestamp.digicert.com
VBOX_TSA_URL_ARGS := /t "$(VBOX_TSA_URL)"
VBOX_TSA_SHA2_URL_ARGS := /tr "$(VBOX_TSA_SHA2_URL)" /td sha256
VBOX_PATH_SIGN_TOOLS := C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64
VBOX_PATH_SELFSIGN := C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\selfsign
VBOX_PATH_WISUMINFO := "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\sysmgmt\msi\scripts\WiSumInf.vbs"
VBOX_PATH_WISUBSTG  := "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\sysmgmt\msi\scripts\WiSubStg.vbs"
VBOX_WITH_DOCS := 1
VBOX_WITH_DOCS_CHM := 1
VBOX_WITH_DOCS_PACKING := 1
VBOX_HAVE_XMLLINT := C:\xmllint\bin\xmllint.exe
VBOX_PATH_DOCBOOK        := C:/DocBook/xsl/
VBOX_PATH_DOCBOOK_DTD    := C:/DocBook/xml/
VBOX_XML_CATALOG         := $(PATH_TARGET)/manual/catalog
VBOX_XML_CATALOG_DOCBOOK := $(PATH_TARGET)/manual/docbook
VBOX_PATH_HTML_HELP_WORKSHOP := "C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop"
VBOX_PDFLATEX := "C:\Program Files\MikTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe"
VBOX_PDFLATEX_CMD := $(VBOX_PDFLATEX) -halt-on-error -interaction batchmode
TOOL_CURL_FETCH := C:\curl\x64\curl.exe
PATH_TOOL_NASM := "C:\Program Files\NASM"
VBOX_INSTALLER_LANGUAGES := en_US
VBOX_WITH_TESTCASES :=
VBOX_WITH_VALIDATIONKIT :=
VBOX_WITH_VBOX_IMG := 1
VBOX_BUILD_PUBLISHER := 
VBOX_WITH_R0_LOGGING := 1
VBOX_PATH_DIFX := C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\redist\DIFx\DIFxAPI\amd64
VBOX_PATH_NSIS := C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS
VBOX_MKISOFS := C:\cdrtools\win32
VBOX_PATH_AUTOIT3 := C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3
VBOX_ONLY_ADDITIONS := 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be downloading anything. On the contrary, it's telling you it can't find "zip.exe".

You'll need to make sure you have that program in your PATH somewhere.

It also doesn't seem to be making an iso in this step.

Comment: I found target "additions-build-win.x86", which performs command "call VBOX_BLD_VM_MSG_END__,Windows/x86 additions build+pack". At least looks like making some installer